# What is the most scaleable and efficient way of managing profile pics

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been asked many times before, but I haven't found an answer that addresses my specific case.

Using PHP & MySQL...

I'm about to add user profile pics to an app and as I see it I have several options. Two of which are as follows:

**1.** Make no reference to the image in the database and store the images
    like so:-

- /assets/avatars/32px/userid.jpg
- /assets/avatars/90px/userid.jpg
- /assets/avatars/256px/userid.jpg

This would mean no extra database lookups as  I will already have the relevant userid.

**1.** Store the relative path in the users_meta table and retrieve the url's using a join when I retrieve user data.

What are the pro's con's of each method?  And if in your opinion, neither method is the best way, what would you consider to be the most efficient and scaleable way of storing/referencing and retrieving user profile pics.

Many thanks

**EDIT:** To add some more detail :

My concern with option number 1 is that I am unsure how the filesystem would cope with 1 million+ files in a single directory.  Would it slow to a crawl?  If so how could I work around this?  Is there a structure that would eliminate this potential issue? Perhaps using the time a user joined as part of the url and storing the images by the month.

e.g.  /assets/avatars/10_2012/small/userid.jpg

with 10_2012 meaning all users who registered in October of 2012.

Or alternatively store only 1000 images in each directory and access the like so:

- /assets/avatars/0/small/userid.jpg
- /assets/avatars/1000/small/userid.jpg
- /assets/avatars/2000/small/userid.jpg

Adding a new directory every time the app reaches 1000 * n users registered.

Would this offer an advantage?

Comment: Why exactly do the other questions not work for you?

Comment: If you would not be concerned with exposing image paths to public then i would go with option NR.1. If you are then go with database option.

Comment: I'm always paranoid about making it possible for an external viewer to request arbitrary profile pictures based on information they can get. I would assign a random number to the image name or hash their name with a secret key.

Comment: Either I am misreading them or they tend to deal with the differences between storing the image directly in the database as a BLOB or referencing with a relative url stored in the DB. Also this needs to support a huge number of users, certainly more than your average use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noted - in case of using file system for your needs you don't have to do an **extra** DB lookup. This saves you time and resources.

The only benefit of using a DB for this that I can see is a "single-point" back-up. But I doubt it's a very valid "pro" or if it even outweighs the extra complexity introduced by an extra level of indirection caused by a DB lookup

**Edit** (to match the edit in the question): The way file systems work greatly depends on the operating system. What is your target platform?

Comment: Thanks YePhick, as I said my instinct leads towards this conclusion, however I am wondering what kind of performance decrease I would begin to see with 1million+ files in each folder.  Would the disk lookups then begin to crawl?  If so is there a file structure/method I could use to prevent this? (by perhaps splitting the files down further, maybe storing them by the month and using the date a user joined as a reference to generate the url?

Comment: I'd say if you end up having 1M+ files in a folder then your design needs to change ;-)

Comment: Thanks again... To answer your edit, Linux...  having thought about it some more I guess a separation structure as I described above would be best?  Would you agree?

Comment: Sorry, I actually won't agree. What advantage do you expect from having 100 directories with 1K files in each vs. a single dir with 100K fiels in it? And yet I'm still puzzled to imagine why would you ever see such a large number of photos from a single user? Maybe if you explain a bit more about what you are trying to achiev it would be easier to suggest something to you

Comment: I would never expect that many files for each user.  However I need to support 1 million+ users. With my original option 1  I would have 1 million+ files in a single folder, 1 for each user of each size.  Surely by having 1000 directories each with 1000 files I would see improved performance as I would imagine that indexing the huge amount of files in a single folder would be slow versus the separation method, causing (I assume every lookup to be significantly slower)

Comment: When you say "surely" - do you have any hard evidence for that or just saying because you feel that way? Here's some food for thought. Consider both directory structure options: 1) single directory with 100K files and 2) 100 directories with 1K files each. Also for the sake of agrument assume your file system (FS) is very busy so the OS doesn't keep the file information around because it gets flushed out often (not a realistic case but it helps with the thinking process). Now, what do we have in terms of file IO for accessing those files in each case?

Comment: In case 1) above we have a single file that holds file pointers and names of 100K elements (this is our directory - after all it's just a file on disk). In case 2) above you always do the following: a) read the top dir (with 100 entries in it) and then b) the second level dir with 1K entries in it.

Comment: It is just a feeling... with no actual evidence to support it.  Other than the results of a quick google such as http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/516598-1-2-millions-files-one-folder

Comment: Now, once you have that in your mind add a real-life caching done by OS and it may be that you actually need to do some real testing before concluding one way or the other. Why do you think at so many companies the software engineers are in "research and development" department? There's always research to be done! ;-)

Comment: Indeed... Testing is probably going to have to be the way I go...  From looking at the way google+ appears to handle their avatars, they seem to user a similar separation structure.  splitting folders into 'AAAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAAB', 'AAAAAAAC' etc... I would asume incrementing the letter after a certain umber of registered users.

Comment: so in order to derive a proper directory's name you have to have a map of those directories to users? Or a clever hash function (I'd suggest this approach, actually) that would more or less evenly split your users into *n* directories. Something along the lines of how DB2 organizes it's DB nodes so that when you are looking for a record you know exactly which DB node to ask based on the key's hash

Comment: Having an enormous number of files **does** negatively impact directory search performance in real life (in my RL experience). "Directory search" includes opening a file. The read (and stream) cost may not change, but the file-open itself can kill you. Yes, it varies by OS and specific filesystem. I would definitely go with gordyr or user1404632 directory partitioning.

Comment: That said, I've written a controller before that maps logical to physical paths so my filesystem could be reconfigurable or replaced by a database BLOB. e.g. `site.com/users/fred/avatar.jpg` is not a real path or filename, and it is equally easy to read the actual image bytes from a database or a file.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with your option 1, but use part of the id's to create your path. For example, if you have six digit ids, you could have the first two digits as part of the path: Id 123456.xyz would become /1/2/123456.xyz. etc...
In this example, with numeric ids, it would limit each directory to contain 1000 files.

Answer (score 1):

What I tend to do in my applications is save the original image.

Upon lookup, either generate a thumbnail (or whatever sized image) and put this into a cache directory, or if the image already exists in the cache directory, return that to the user.

If the person who uploaded the image either deletes or update the original image, you would then also remove it from cache.

It is very useful to do it like this because you don't need to know every dimension the image will be used when saving initially.

Comment: Images can be resized client-side, using `<img width="xx" height="xx" />`. Why would you every need to know beforehand the required dimensions of the image?

Comment: There is more than one way to resize an image, for example, if you're saving either a thumbnail, you might only want the middle portion of the image instead of scaling the whole thing down.  This also helps on transport costs as you're not sending a potential 5mb image when all the user needs is a 32x32 icon.

Comment: @arxanas so the user don't have to download big image to display small one?